graph shares root api can not return more than 200 items
I try to fetch all items in a shared SharePoint folder.
Currently I am using:
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/shares/u!{folder}=/root?expand=children"

Response:
"children": [] // max 200 items
"folder": {
   "childCount": 216
},

I want to get all 216 Items.
I tried:

&$top=999 (still 200)
&$count=true (not supported by this endpoint)
&$skipTopen (@odata.nextLink not found in the Response)

Am I missing something?
